# Simplify this trigonometric equation (identities)

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

Please simplify these trigonometric identities and describe step by step (wording).

$\frac{\sec \theta-\csc \theta}{1-\cot\theta}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change secϴ to 1/cosϴ, cscϴ to 1/sinϴ, and cotϴ to cosϴ/sinϴ so you have

$$\frac{\frac{1}{cosϴ}-\frac{1}{sinϴ}}{1-\frac{cosϴ}{sinϴ}}$$

Now multiply both the numerator and denominator of 1/cosϴ by sinϴ, the numerator and denominator of 1/sinϴ by cosϴ, and the numerator and denominator of 1 by sinϴ in order to add the two terms together (remember for fractions, if the denominators are equal, then just add the numerators together) so you have

$$\frac{\frac{sinϴ}{sinϴcosϴ}-\frac{cosϴ}{sinϴcosϴ}}{\frac{sinϴ}{sinϴ}-\frac{cosϴ}{sinϴ}}$$

Now you just add the numerators so you have

$$\frac{\frac{sinϴ-cosϴ}{sinϴcosϴ}}{\frac{sinϴ-cosϴ}{sinϴ}}$$

Now dividing by a fraction is the same as multiplying by the reciprocal of it so the operation turns into

$$\frac{sinϴ-cosϴ}{sinϴcosϴ}*\frac{sinϴ}{sinϴ-cosϴ}$$

Now you see that the numerator of the first term cancels with the denominator of the second term so you are left with

$$\frac{sinϴ}{sinϴcosϴ}$$

Now the sinϴ in the numerator cancels with the sinϴ in the denominator so you are left with

$$\frac{1}{cosϴ}$$

Or simply

$$secϴ$$

Comment: Thank you for helping. Taking the quotient relations on -cotx only ended with sec^2x. :D

Answer (score 0):

Let $A = \frac{\sec\theta - \csc\theta}{1-\cot\theta}$

$A = \frac{\frac{1}{\cos\theta}-\frac{1}{\sin\theta}}{1-\frac{\cos\theta}{\sin\theta}}$

Now we make common denominators like so:

$A = \frac{\frac{\sin\theta}{\sin\theta \cdot \cos\theta}-\frac{\cos\theta}{sin\theta\cdot \cos\theta}}{\frac{\sin\theta}{\sin\theta}-\frac{\cos\theta}{\sin\theta}}$

$A = \frac{\sin\theta - \cos\theta}{\sin\theta\cdot\cos\theta} \cdot \frac{\sin\theta}{\sin\theta-\cos\theta}$

Now we can cancel out leaving $A = \frac{1}{\cos\theta} = \sec\theta$